# @Test creates new record

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I recently started to using Junit. So im newbie.

When i use @Test anotation above method and run that with method with Junit. 
It creates a new record. Is this normal or am i making a mistake?

```
    @Before
public void setUp() {
    restTemp = new RestTemplate();
}

@Test
public void testCreateOwner() {
    Owner owner = new Owner();
    owner.setFirstName("new");
    owner.setLastName("record");
    URI location = restTemp.postForLocation("http://localhost:8080/rest/owner", owner);

    Owner owner2 = restTemp.getForObject(location, Owner.class);
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(owner2.getFirstName(), Matchers.equalTo(owner.getFirstName()));
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(owner2.getLastName(), Matchers.equalTo(owner.getLastName()));
}
```

My create owner method is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owner", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<URI> createOwner(@RequestBody Owner owner) {
    try {
        petClinicService.createOwner(owner);
        Long id = owner.getId();
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(id).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

and my createOwner method impl is

```
public void create(Owner owner) {
    owner.setId(new Date().getTime());
    ownersMap.put(owner.getId(), owner);

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: well you do call `petClinicService.createOwner(owner);` from your test...

Comment: Yeah. I know but how can i test it otherwise ?

Comment: the dirty way would be to delete them in `@After`, since you are using spring search for that - there are other ways too

Comment: Like second database ?

Comment: and btw these tests are not unit tests anymore... IMO. you have the server running while the tests run also, otherwise your tests will fail. Well, yes, a second in memory database would one option, but even so, there are junit `@Rule`, spring's `@Rollback(value = true)`, etc, that will clean for you

Comment: Well, thank you i need to do more research on annotations then.

Comment: no no, not annotations, but spring-test *in general*

Comment: FYI Eugene is the #1 spring guy, you find a lot of useful info on his website. ;-)

Comment: can i get his website URL :)

Comment: You can use MockMvc or RestAssured to test Rest API without adding new records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing the persistence and it is working normal. However I would suggest deleting the entries that you created in your test, either in the test method or creating a separate method (in which you delete) and annotate it with `@After`.

For example using this:

```
 @Before
 @After
 public void deleteTestUsers(){
    // call delete endpoint
 }
```

Using such a snippet you make sure that

- Before running the test you got a "known" state - meaning that the entry does not exist.
- After running the test you clear up the created entry - hence leaving it in a "known" state.

Kind of like the public toilet. - Clean before & clean after. ;-)

Comment: So its normal I need to do delete with @After Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Normally you would have 2 databases, one for the sting the other for production.